# Specification of Bitcoin RPC getbalances

Tags: wallet, bitcoind, address, json-rpc

I would like to track balances using address, but I have a few questions.

1. If I don't use the rescan option, will the balance be incorrect?
2. Why is the balance off when I check it against an external balance inquiry site?

The procedure using the API was to execute `importaddress`(no rescan) and then `getbalances`.

Because the balance was off, I executed `importaddress` with rescan, but the balance was off when I tried again.

I tried several times with other addresses, but it didn't work!
Should I change Wallet every time I look up a different address?

For example,

```
❯ curl --user user:password --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id": "curltest", "method": "importaddress", "params": [ "38XnPvu9PmonFU9WouPXUjYbW91wa5MerL", "", false ]}' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://--.--.--.--:----
{"result":null,"error":null,"id":"curltest"}

❯ curl --user user:password --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id": "curltest", "method": "getbalances", "params": []}' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://--.--.--.--:---- | jq .
{
  "result": {
    "mine": {
      "trusted": 0,
      "untrusted_pending": 0,
      "immature": 0
    },
    "watchonly": {
      "trusted": 3239.83164697,
      "untrusted_pending": 16.05599144,
      "immature": 184.81980076
    }
  },
  "error": null,
  "id": "curltest"
}
```

However, when referring to an external site, it is significantly off.
https://chainflyer.bitflyer.jp/tool/balance
[image]

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I don't use the rescan option, will the balance be incorrect?

Definitely. Without rescanning, the wallet won't know about any transactions that affect your balance.

> Why is the balance off when I check it against an external balance inquiry site?

There is no way to answer that without knowing what you were looking at, or what you were expecting. Please update your question with details like which address you imported, what else is imported in your wallet, and what reference you used to compare with.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me!
I've updated the question, what do you think?

Comment: Are you importing multiple addresses into the same wallet? `getbalances` (and other balance RPCs) report the balance of the entire wallet.

Comment: That's right! Thanks to you I understand about `getbalances`. So if I want to import other addresses, I have to separate Wallet. Or is there an API to remove the import of addresses?